# Euler product over a finite subset of composite numbers

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, infinite-product

The product $$\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\frac{p^n}{p^n-1}=\zeta(n)$$ is well-known. This works over primes, and only over the entire set of them.

Is any similar expression known for composites? For a finite subset of them?

e.g. $$\prod_{c\text{ composite, c}=c_{i}}^{c=c_{j}}\frac{c^n}{c^n-1}=f(m)$$ for some $f$.

This is generic. If such an expression is not known, is anything known for the case $i=1$ and $n=1$? If not, then for $i=n=1$ and $j=\infty$? If that is also not known, is anything known on $\lim \inf f(m)$ or $\lim \sup f(m)$?

Comment: Consider L-functions $L(s,\chi)=\prod_p(1-\chi(p)p^{-s})^{-1}$

Answer (score 5):

Surely we can say something in the case of the set of all composite numbers and for an integer exponent. From the following representation of Gamma function $$\Gamma\left(z\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{n^{z-1}n!}{z\left(z+1\right)\cdots\left(z+n-1\right)}$$ it is possible to prove that $$\prod_{n\geq0}\frac{\left(n+a_{1}\right)\cdots\left(n+a_{k}\right)}{\left(n+b_{1}\right)\cdots\left(n+b_{k}\right)}=\frac{\Gamma\left(b_{1}\right)\cdots\Gamma\left(b_{k}\right)}{\Gamma\left(a_{1}\right)\cdots\Gamma\left(a_{k}\right)},\,a_{1}+\dots+a_{k}=b_{1}+\dots+b_{k}$$ for $a_{i},b_{j}\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}^{-},$ (see Whittaker and Watson, A course of modern analysis, $4$th edition, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, $1927$, section $12.13$) then if $k>1$ is a positive integer we have $$\prod_{n\geq2}\frac{n^{k}}{n^{k}-1}=\prod_{n\geq0}\frac{\left(n+2\right)^{k}}{\left(n+2-\omega_{0}^{k}\right)\cdots\left(n+2-\omega_{k-1}^{k}\right)}=\frac{\Gamma\left(2-\omega_{0}^{k}\right)\cdots\Gamma\left(2-\omega_{k-1}^{k}\right)}{\Gamma\left(2\right)^{k}}$$ where $\omega_{j}^{k}=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ij}{k}\right)$. Then, since $\Gamma(2)=\Gamma(1)=1$, $$\prod_{c\text{ composite}}\frac{c^{k}}{c^{k}-1}=\color{red}{\frac{\Gamma\left(2-\omega_{1}^{k}\right)\cdots\Gamma\left(2-\omega_{k-1}^{k}\right)}{\zeta\left(k\right)}}.$$
**ADDENDUM**: I think it is interesting to see how the answer of Daniel D. is linked to mine; from the [power series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html) $$\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{n}\zeta\left(n\right)}{n}=\gamma x+\log\left(\Gamma\left(x+1\right)\right),\,-1<x\leq1$$ we have $$\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{n}\left(\zeta\left(n\right)-1\right)}{n}=\left(\gamma-1\right)x+\log\left(\Gamma\left(x+1\right)\right)+\log\left(\left(x+1\right)\right)$$ which can be extended to $x=-1$ and where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Now recalling that if $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}a_{n}x^{n}$ then we have the multisection formula $$\sum_{n\geq0}a_{qn+p}x^{qn+p}=\frac{1}{q}\sum_{j=0}^{q-1}\omega_{q}^{-jp}f\left(\omega_{q}^{j}x\right)$$ where $\omega_{q}^{j}$ is a primitive $q$-root of the unity, we get, assuming that $f(x):=\left(\gamma-1\right)x+\log\left(\Gamma\left(x+1\right)\right)+\log\left(\left(x+1\right)\right)$ and $m>1$, that $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\zeta\left(mn\right)-1}{n}=\lim_{x\rightarrow-1^{+}}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}f\left(\omega_{m}^{j}x\right)=\color{red}{\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}\log\left(\Gamma\left(2-\omega_{m}^{j}\right)\right)}.$$ Notice that we used the relations $\sum_{j=0}^{q-1}\omega_{q}^{j}=0$ and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow-1^{+}}\left[\log\left(\Gamma\left(x+1\right)\right)+\log\left(\left(x+1\right)\right)\right]$$ $$=\lim_{x\rightarrow-1^{+}}\left[\log\left(\Gamma\left(x\omega_{q}^{0}+1\right)\right)+\log\left(\left(x\omega_{q}^{0}+1\right)\right)\right]=0.$$

Comment: I get that $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\zeta(mn)-1}{n}
=\lim_{x\rightarrow-1^{+}}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}[(\gamma-1)\omega_{m}^{j}x+ \log(\Gamma(\omega_{m}^{j}x+1))+\log((\omega_{m}^{j}x+1))]
=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}[\log(\Gamma(1-\omega_{m}^{j}))+\log((1-\omega_{m}^{j}))]
=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}[\log(\Gamma(1-\omega_{m}^{j}))+\log((1-\omega_{m}^{j}))]
=\text{...?...}=\color{red}{\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}\log(\Gamma(2-\omega_{m}^{j}))}.$ how do I proceed with the rest?

Comment: @DanielD. Note that on the LHS actually you have $\sum_{n}\frac{\zeta\left(mn\right)-1}{mn}$ (you have to consider the coefficient $a_{mn}$) but the factor $1/m$ is eliminated since it is present also in the RHS. Then, use $$\log\left(\Gamma\left(a+1\right)\right)+\log\left(a+1\right)=\log\left(\left(a+1\right)\Gamma\left(a+1\right)\right)=\log\left(\Gamma\left(a+2\right)\right).$$

Comment: oh great many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

My bit,  with some manipulations one can relate the zeta function $\zeta(m)=f_p(m)$ with the prime zeta function $P$

$f_p(m)
=\prod_p\frac{1}{1-p^{-m}}
=\exp\ln\prod_p\frac{1}{1-p^{-m}}
=\exp\sum_p\ln(\frac{1}{1-p^{-m}})
=\exp\sum_p\sum_k\frac{p^{-mk}}{k}
=\exp\sum_k\frac{1}{k}\sum_p\frac{1}{p^{mk}}
=\exp\sum_k\frac{1}{k}P(mk)
$

Now call $f_n(m)$ the product over all the naturals and let's do the same set of manipulation than before

$f_n(m)
=\prod_n\frac{1}{1-n^{-m}}
=\exp\ln\prod_n\frac{1}{1-n^{-m}}
=\exp\sum_n\ln(\frac{1}{1-n^{-m}})
=\exp\sum_n\sum_k\frac{n^{-mk}}{k}
=\exp\sum_k\frac{1}{k}\sum_n\frac{1}{n^{mk}}
=\exp\sum_k\frac{1}{k}(\zeta(mk)-1)
$

Finally the product over all composites $f_c(m)$ can be obtained as the quotient of the two other expressions since $f_n(m)=\prod_n\frac{1}{1-n^{-m}}=\prod_c\frac{1}{1-c^{-m}}\prod_p\frac{1}{1-p^{-m}}=f_c(m)f_p(m)$ so

$f_c(m)=f_n(m)/f_p(m)=\exp\sum_k\frac{1}{k}(\zeta(mk)-1-P(mk))$

if $i\neq1$ and $j\neq\infty$ instead of $\zeta(mk)$ and $P(mk)$ we should get a partial sum of those.

Comment: Note that the product $f(m)$ must start from $n=2$, so you can not have $\sum_{k}\frac{\zeta\left(km\right)}{k}$ (which is, indeed, a divergent series) but $\sum_{k}\frac{\zeta\left(km\right)-1}{k}$. However it is interesting since it is related to my answer by a series multisection argument (+1)

Comment: @MarcoCantarini Thanks! I wouldn't have noticed it by myself, corrected, I was thinking both answer should be related but couldn't see how so I would happy to see the argument if you feel like adding it and where could I find a proof of the identity that you use? I was looking for it but couldn't find it but I know is correct so +1.

Comment: I add to my answer a reference for the formula I used and the link between the two anserws :)

Answer (score 2):

This Answer addresses the coefficients of the Dirichlet-Series of $f(s) = \prod_{c \text{ comp}} \frac 1{1-c^{-s}}$.

We introduce
$$g(s) = \prod_{n=2}^\infty (1 + n^{-s} + n^{-2s} + \dots ),$$ which is a holomorpic function on $\Re s > 1$, as $\left | 1 - \frac 1{1-n^{-s}}\right | \ll n^{-s}$.
This can be re-written as a dirichlet-series
$$g(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c(n) n^{-s},$$
where $c(n) = \#\{(e_2, e_3, \dots) \in \mathbb N_{\geq 0}^* | 2^{e_2} 3^{e_3} 4^{e_4} \dots = n \}$ is the amount of [multiplicative partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_partition) of $n$. With $\mu$ (the [möbius-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function)) we obtain
$$\prod_{c \text{ comp}} \frac 1{1-c^{-s}} = \zeta(s)^{-1} g(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n) n^{-s},$$
where $a(n) = (c \star \mu)(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) c(\frac nd)$.

Comment: +1, I had heard about integer partition and set partition but not about multiplicative partition, pretty nice!